# batch file - looking for way if both folder exist then proceed else skip the operation

Tags: batch-file

I have a below batch file where if both folder1 and folder2 both exist then I want to execute else don't want to do anything.

Here even my folder NOT exist, I am getting `echo` message `Both folders exist`. What I am doing wrong here?

```
@ECHO OFF

set folder1="C:\Temp1"
set folder2="C:\Temp2"

IF EXIST %folder1% IF EXIST %folder2% goto bothfound

:bothfound
echo Both folders exist.
goto end

:end
echo Done.
pause
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because you don't have a GOTO to bypass the :bothfound block. After the if exist statements, it continues on because it never invoked the goto. After you do your if exist, you need a goto end or a goto to a not found block.

example:

```
IF EXIST %folder1% IF EXIST %folder2% goto bothfound
goto end

:bothfound
```

Comment: The correct syntax is `Set "folder1=C:\Temp1"`. Additionally, to check for the existence of a directory, you should  trail your directory with a backslash e.g. `Set "folder1=C:\Temp1\"` or `If Exist "%folder1%\" If Exist "%folder2%\"...`

Comment: @user584018, please heed my advice, _instead of seemingly ignoring it_.

Comment: no issue @Compo, I have other issue though....https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53011892/batch-file-why-both-goto-labels-executes-when-both-folder1-2-exist