# batch file - why both goto labels executes when both folder1 & 2 exist

Tags: batch-file

For below batch file, When both or any one folder NOT exist then ONLY `:notfound` label execute which is correct, but when both folder exist, then both `:bothfound` and `:notfound` labels execute.

How we can run ONLY execute `:bothfound` when both folder Temp1 and Temp2 exist?

```
@ECHO OFF

set "folder1=C:\Temp1\"
set "folder2=C:\Temp2\"

IF EXIST %folder1% IF EXIST %folder2% goto bothfound
goto notfound


:bothfound
echo Both folders exist.

:notfound
echo either one or both folder not exist.

echo Done.
pause
```

Comment: What didn't you understand about the advice you were given in your previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53009512/batch-file-looking-for-way-if-both-folder-exist-then-proceed-else-skip-the-ope)?

Comment: Please correct your `Set` syntax as previously commented, and then do the same with your `If` line.

Comment: Compo, I tried that also, same result....

Comment: It wasn't an answer, it was a comment. If you're provided with advice, but ignore it, _why would we go to the effort of helping you further?_

Comment: @Compo, I edited my code as per your comment, event I'm getting same result, if both folder exist, then both goto labels executes...any reason why?

Comment: Please stop creating a javascript snippet out of your batch file code.  That is not correct.  I have fixed it three times now in two of your questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Same problem as your other [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53009512/batch-file-looking-for-way-if-both-folder-exist-then-proceed-else-skip-the-ope).

Batch files process top to bottom. If a goto is not employed to skip lines, it will execute the next line. These are not methods like you think of in a modern programming language; the start of a new label doe not imply an end to the prior label.

```
:bothfound
echo Both folders exist.
goto end

:notfound
echo either one or both folder not exist.
goto end

:end
echo Done.
pause
```